# Can we create view on specific partition of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-view

There is table which is partitioned on month names.

Can we create a VIEW on specific partition of a table?

For example: view has to be created on January partition of table.

Comment: You add a WHERE clause to the query based on what data is in the partition.  In your example, just `WHERE [Month] = 'January'`.  The problem with stating any hardcoded partition would be when that partition at some point goes away.  Then your view is broken.

Comment: You could use [`$PARTITION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/partition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-returning-all-rows-from-one-partition-of-a-partitioned-table-or-index); though I have no idea how performant such a query would be.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Just add a proper where clause to your view, and it will only access the one partition. What problem are you actually trying to solve with this?

Comment: @Larnu Good idea, `$PARTITION` is pretty efficient, it will seek straight to the right partition